# :: jQuery :: JSON Find first key and replace dynamically

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get json data and displaying table format. However it is working as expected if I use first key/object (heading) as manual.

Sample JSON files for the same:

- https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list
- https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA

> **I am facing issues as user can embed JSON by their own with different**
> **structure.**

- How can I replace my first key based on dynamic JSON url
- If there is no arry in json data, how can I fetch the data from JSON.

Working example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/ds2x1qvj/57/)**

JSON File: https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list

Sample data from above URL
[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
var atd, atr, temp;

fetch('https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    data.items.map(myList => {
        var __keys = Object.keys(myList); 
        var __values = Object.values(myList);
        $.each(__values, function(index,myList) {
            atd = '<td>'+myList+'</td>'
            atr += atd;
            if((__keys.length) -1 == index){
                temp+=  '<tr>'+atr+'</tr>'
                atr = '';
            }
        })
    });
    $('#data table').html(temp) 
})
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Another JSON file**: https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA
[image]

For the above JSON file, I have to change code as:

```
data.site.docs.map(myList => {
```

[image]

Comment: You don't know in advance on which level your data is? If it were just for the property name you could use Object.keys like you are doing already in the map function. Perhaps look for objects containing an id property?

Comment: You can search for you wanted key by traversing down and up. However you would still need your lowest key and it can not be a duplicate key somewhere else.

Comment: You could check if a property exists and if it doesn't, use an alternative format - but you'd need to know the *possible* formats, eg `var items = data.items || data.site.docs;`

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for the answer. I need to get properties (`.items & .site.docs`) dynamically instead of statically typing. `Eg: var __items = data.xxx` etc...

Comment: So how do you know what the properties are going to be called?  data.files?  data.widgets? data.organistation.location.site.fields.documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution

Get all the nested child arrays and use the arrays to display data. Here I have only used the first array. You can iterate and use all arrays if needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/r0uocnzv/

```
var atd, atr, temp;
let resultData = [];
//fetch('https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA')
fetch('https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
  findChildArrays(data);
  console.log(resultData)
   if(resultData && resultData[0]) {
    resultData[0].map(myList => {
      var __keys = Object.keys(myList); 
      var __values = Object.values(myList);
      $.each(__values, function(index,myList) {
        atd = '<td>'+myList+'</td>'
        atr += atd;
        if((__keys.length) -1 == index){
          temp+=  '<tr>'+atr+'</tr>'
          atr = '';
        }
      })
    });
  } 

    $('#data table').html(temp) 
});

findChildArrays = function(data = {}) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    if(Array.isArray(data[key])) {
         resultData.push(data[key])
    }
  else
    findChildArrays(data[key] || [], )
  });
  return resultData;
};
```

Comment: Thanks **@Nitha** for the solutions. I am accepting and upvoting your answer.